Run-Time Error 91 (object variable or with block variable not set) on VBA Email code "mailItem.Display" after IF statements
I have some code that fills an existing Outlook email template (with graphics!) with different variables i.e. name, ID number, etc. It works with both ".oft" and ".msg" templates stored on OneDrive. It's particularly fantastic when I can use "mailItem.Send" instead of "mailItem.Display" at the end. Which...I can only do when I trust the code.
Lately I've tried to alter the code so that it calls for 1 of 2 templates depending on a variable. But it often gives me Error 91 (object variable or with block variable not set) on "mailItem.Display" right after I call a template and it's driving me CRAZY.
PLEASE NOTE I'd rather do two "If - Then" statements than an "If - Then - Else" statement because there are 3 variable types and only 2 require email generation.
It worked fine for one variable type:

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 7) <> ""
    'Call Outlook template
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\template.msg")
    mailItem.Display 

When I added the If statements below, the 91 error appeared on "mail.Item.Display":
Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 7) <> ""
Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Then Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\Atemplate.msg")
    If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Tyep B" Then Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\Btemplate.msg")
    mailItem.Display <<<<<ERROR


Later in the code the If statements worked fine for different ".Subjects".
With mailItem
        .Display
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Or Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type B" Then .To = Toemail
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Then .Subject = "Login Information for " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + "
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type B" Then .Subject = "Your other Information is ready - " + Firstname + " " + Lastname

What I Tried
I tried just one If statement (and made sure that Type A was the top row in the Excel). No change.
I tried moving the EmpID = Sheet1.Cells... code chunk above Set mailApp.... No change.
I tried Removing "Set" from "Set mailItem" in both If statements. No change.
I tried moving the mailItem.Display to the end of each If statement, but the error moved down to my variables (EmpID...)
Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 7) <> ""
Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Then Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\Atemplate.msg") And mailItem.Display
    If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type B" Then Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\Btemplate.msg") And mailItem.Display
    

EmpID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1)     <<<<<<ERROR
    Lastname = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2)
    Firstname = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3)
    UserID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5)
    EmailID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6)
    Toemail = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7)

I tried setting Sheet1.Cells (r, 4) as a String variable Dim VariableType = String VariableType = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) but that didn't help either.
Don't know if it's related but I could never get it to go r+1 for one variable. Tried:
VariableType = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) If VariableType = "Type C" Then r = r + 1
and
If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type C" Then r = r + 1
And neither worked.
Full code that works below:


Sub Send_email_from_template_my_code_1()

Dim EmpID As String
Dim Lastname As String
Dim Firstname As String
Dim VariableType As String
Dim UserID As String
Dim EmailID As String
Dim Toemail As String
Dim FromEmail As String

Dim mailApp As Object
Dim mailItem As Object
R=row number, and r = r + 1 will change the row number.
Dim r As Long
r = 2

Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object


VariableType = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4)
If VariableType = "Type C" Then r = r + 1

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 7) <> ""
    'Call Outlook template
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\template.msg")
    mailItem.Display
    

    EmpID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1)
    Lastname = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2)
    Firstname = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3)
    UserID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5)
    EmailID = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6)
    Toemail = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7)
    
   
    With mailItem
        .Display
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Or Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type B" Then .To = Toemail
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type A" Then .Subject = "Login Information for " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + "
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 4) = "Type B" Then .Subject = "Your other Information is ready - " + Firstname + " " + Lastname
        

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="[NAME]")
                oRng.Text = Firstname + " " + Lastname
            Loop
        End With
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="[EmpID]")
                oRng.Text = EmpID
            Loop
        End With
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="[EmailID]")
                oRng.Text = EmailID
            Loop
        End With
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="[UserID]")
                oRng.Text = UserID
            Loop
        End With
        
    End With

    

mailItem.Display


r = r + 1
Loop



End Sub




Tyep B ? Typo .

there are 3 variable types and only 2 require email generation. You need to put the email creation code in an IF block so that you can skip over it for the  Type C. Also you only need to create Oulook.Application object once, not a new one for every email

Untested as I don't have Outlook
Option Explicit
Sub Send_email_from_template_my_code_1()

    Dim EmpID As String, Lastname As String, Firstname As String
    Dim VariableType As String, UserID As String
    Dim EmailID As String, Toemail As String, FromEmail As String
    
    Dim mailApp As Object, mailItem As Object
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim olInsp As Object, wdDoc As Object, oRng As Object
    Dim sText As String, r As Long, template As String
    
    r = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 7) <> ""
        
        VariableType = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4)
        If VariableType = "Type A" Then
            template = "Atemplate.msg"
            sText = "Login Information for "
        ElseIf VariableType = "Type B" Then
            template = "Btemplate.msg"
            sText = "Your other Information is ready - "
        Else
            template = ""
        End If

        If template <> "" Then
            With Sheet1
                EmpID = .Cells(r, 1)
                Lastname = .Cells(r, 2)
                Firstname = .Cells(r, 3)
                UserID = .Cells(r, 5)
                EmailID = .Cells(r, 6)
                Toemail = .Cells(r, 7)
            End With
    
            'Call Outlook template
            Set mailItem = mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("filepath\" & template)
            With mailItem
                .To = Toemail
                .Subject = sText & Firstname & " " & Lastname
                .display
      
                Set olInsp = .GetInspector
                Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
                Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
                With oRng.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:="[NAME]")
                        oRng.Text = Firstname & " " & Lastname
                    Loop
                End With
                Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
                With oRng.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:="[EmpID]")
                        oRng.Text = EmpID
                    Loop
                End With
                Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
                With oRng.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:="[EmailID]")
                        oRng.Text = EmailID
                    Loop
                End With
                Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
                With oRng.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:="[UserID]")
                        oRng.Text = UserID
                    Loop
                End With
                
            End With
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Set mailApp = Nothing
End Sub


You already got a suggestion but I'd also add this.
You can create a sub to do the find and replace
'Replace text `placeHolder` with `txt` in Word Range `rng`
Sub ReplaceRangeText(rng As Object, placeHolder As String, txt As String)
    With rng.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=placeHolder)
            rng.Text = txt
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Then you can do (eg):
    With mailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(templatePath)
        .Display
        .Subject = Subj
        .To = rw.Cells(7).Value
            
        Set wdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        ReplaceRangeText wdDoc.Range, "[NAME]", FullName
        ReplaceRangeText wdDoc.Range, "[EmpID]", rw.Cells(1).Value   'EmpID
        ReplaceRangeText wdDoc.Range, "[EmailID]", rw.Cells(6).Value 'EmailID
        ReplaceRangeText wdDoc.Range, "[UserID]", rw.Cells(5).Value  'UserID
    End With

